# In which folder should I put "global" shared partial templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, templates, dry

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I am planning to use partial templates. All classes in my application would use same partials so I have to decide where to located all those.

Is it a good idea to put "global" shared partial templates in the `lib` folder? If no, what is a common practice to choose the folder where to put those? Any advice on how to properly name and load that folder?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The standard is placing all shared partials in `app/views/shared`, and referencing them as

```
render :partial => 'shared/partial_name'
```

If you have a standard "row in a list" partial (say, for an index page), you could use a shared partial like:

```
# To render a single object row:
render :partial => 'shared/item', :locals => { :item => @item }
# Or to render them all:
render :partial => 'shared/item', :collection => @items
```

Comment: Is this still accurate for Rails 4?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon Yes, works with Rails 4.

Comment: what about rails 5??, is there a better way in rails 5 or to use the same

Comment: No longer true. Rails guide says app/views/application [This makes app/views/application/ a great place for your shared partials, which can then be rendered in your ERB as such](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: @notapatch Note that all the examples on that page actually use views/shared, e.g. menu, footer, etc.

Comment: @BarryKelly - Since I made this comment I found this dhh quote on the subject: It's [app/views/application] a side-effect from this reasonable case: EmployeesController < PeopleController, which will look first for employees/show, then fall back to look for people/show. It was never intended to fall all the way back to look for application/show. That's an unintended side-effect. github.com/rails/rails/pull/9911#issuecomment-15462128 ... end quote. Without better guidance, I'm ok with `shared` or `application`.

Comment: This works with Rails 6

Answer (score 16):

**Rails 4:**

put the partials you intend to use through out your application in `/app/views/application`

Then anywhere in your application you can easily:

```
render partial: 'partial_name', variable_name: variable
```

The added benefit is that you can always override the partial in a particular view space by redefining what that partial means in `/app/views/controller_name/_partial_name.html.erb` and the calls to the partial will then reference the more specific context you're in. If that doesn't exist you get the application level partial.

Suggestion taken from [Thoughtbot](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/directory-for-shared-partials-in-rails)

Comment: This doesn't work when using namespaced controllers. Then it expects the files to be under `app/views/NAMESPACE/application`, without the fallback to non-namespaced

Comment: On second evaluation; this problem only arises when running my specs, but not when just using the application..

Answer (score 4):

Conventions is to put them under `app/views/shared`

If you're going to have many partials, I'd recommend you putting them into subdirectories of that folder, whatever makes sense to your application, since having many partials in one directory is generally not a good practice.